# PHP | Search for value in previous csv file

Tags: php, csv

I am creating a csv file called "New.csv" taking data from another csv file and currently my code is this:

```
<?php

    $checkFile = "allSkuRO.csv";
    $inputFile = "product_stock_ro.csv";
    $outputFile = "updateStock_qty_ro.csv";
    $inputHandle = fopen($inputFile, 'r');
    $outputHandle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
    $headers = fgetcsv($inputHandle);
    fputcsv($outputHandle, ["sku", "qty", "dateproduzione1", "produzione1" ]);

    while ( false !== $fields = fgetcsv($inputHandle) ) {
        $fields = array_combine($headers, $fields);
        foreach ( $fields as $name => $field )  {
            if (!empty(trim($field)))   {
                $subFields = explode(";", $field );
                fputcsv($outputHandle, [$subFields[0],$subFields[2],$subFields[3],$subFields[5]]);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($inputHandle);
    fclose($outputHandle);


?>
```

Everything is working correctly but I am missing the last part.
In the foreach that returns the values to the new csv file I would like to be able to do a check in the file "allSkuRO.csv" in the column called "PRODUCTCODE".
The check would be this:

- If the value of $subFields[0] from the "New.csv" file is found in the "PRODUCTCODE" column of the "allSkuRO.csv" file then it prints the value of the "sku" column that is in the same row as the corresponding value of "PRODUCTCODE".

How can I do this?

I hope I have explained myself well

Comment: Open the other CSV file, import into an array, search the array each time. (If the file is too large to import into an array without using up excessive memory, you might have to read the file rows again each time instead)

Comment: Okay, i try this. But to get the value after that in the same row where it matches, how do I do that?

Comment: You'll have to count the rows. If you import into an array, that's easy - just use the array index

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: an example of what, specifically? You surely know how to access a specific index of an array (in fact I know you do, because you've done it in the code above)? And you surely know how to create a variable in PHP, set it to 0, and increase its value by 1 every time you loop?

Comment: Example of this: If value is inside array so print value of array that correspond

Comment: I've explained to you how it can be done, by outlining the steps you'd need to take. Which part of what I described are you stuck on implementing? Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: You can also turn `allSkuRO.csv` into an associative array that maps product codes to sku. Then searching the array will be more efficient.

Comment: There's no `New.csv` in the code snippet. Did you mean `updateStock_qty_ro.csv`?

Comment: In short, you simply read, modify, write. This has very little to do with CSV, to be honest. CSV as metaformat only allows sequential reads and writes, which is the only problem I see with combining data from the two file if they don't fit in memory. Can you (for a proper [mcve]) provide usable example input data and according expected and actual output data?